# Temporary deactivation of a subscriber

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I'm thinking about possibly useful feature that I'm currently missing in ROS and would like to hear your opinion on it.
I'm currently writing a node that subscribes to a pointcloud-Topic but in fact only uses a pointcloud every minute or so. It would be useful to be able to temporarily disable the subscriber so that the pointcloud-publisher can use getNumSubscribers to decide if the CPU-hungry stereo-algorithm has to be run or not.

This effect could currently only be achieved by calling subscriber.shutdown and subscribing again later but that requires to store the topic_name and more boilerplate code.

Who would use this feature?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231320/temporary-deactivation-of-a-subscriber/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2016-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wouldn't `ros::topic::waitForMessage(..)` work here? See [ros::topic](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html) for the docs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-04-07**:
That's perfect for this use case. Thanks :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-07**:
Perfect example of an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) this then :).

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-04-07**:
If that was the case, how could you post that answer without asking which problem I really wanted to solve? I provided X and Y ;)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-07**:\

> If that was the case, how could you post that answer without asking which problem I really wanted to solve?

I've seen my share of "I need to temporarily disable a publisher/subscriber" questions.

> I provided X and Y ;)

True. That made it easier :).